# How to convert bytes to string in Python 3 to concatenate(serialized_data,signature)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a prototype for securing deserialization adding a signature to the serialized data, but when I try to concatenate the signature with the serialized data it throws an error.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        #Adding the signature to the data
        file_object.write(signature + serialized)
```

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

And if I try to convert the serialized data into a string it also throws an error

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        #Adding the signature to the data
        serializedStr = serialized.decode('utf-8')
        file_object.write(signature + serializedStr)
```

> serializedStr = serialized.decode('utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'
>   codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

**How can I add the signature to the serialized data?**

**Full Code**

```
import pickle
import json
import hashlib
import hmac


class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

filename = 'user.file'
KEY = b'secret'


user = User('david')
serialized = pickle.dumps(user)
#calculate the signature
signature = hmac.new(KEY, serialized, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    #Adding the signature to the data
    print(type(serialized))
    print(type(signature))
    #serializedStr = serialized.decode('utf-8')
    file_object.write(signature + serialized)

with open(filename, 'rb') as file_object:
    raw_data = file_object.read()
    if(len(raw_data) == len(signature)):
        read_signature = raw_data[:len(signature)]
        read_data = raw_data[len(signature):]
        computed_signature = hmac.new(KEY, read_data, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        if hmac.compare_digest(computed_signature, read_signature):
            userDeserialized = pickle.loads(read_data)
            print (userDeserialized.name)
```

Comment: I am afraid, that decode this as utf-8 won't work because the data dumped by pickle has another encoding, but If You relay need to cast it to str, You can use `latin1`

Comment: @Take_Care_ Respect for you sir, encoding to `latin1` worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.digest()` not `.hexdigest()` to get a byte string that can be prepended to the serialized data byte string.  Open the file for binary read/write:

```
import pickle
import json
import hashlib
import hmac

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

filename = 'user.file'
KEY = b'secret'

user = User('david')
serialized = pickle.dumps(user)
#calculate the signature
signature = hmac.new(KEY, serialized, hashlib.sha256).digest() # not .hexdigest()

with open(filename, 'wb') as file_object:                 # binary write
    file_object.write(signature + serialized)

with open(filename, 'rb') as file_object:                 # binary read
    raw_data = file_object.read()
    if len(raw_data) >= len(signature):                   # need >= here
        read_signature = raw_data[:len(signature)]
        read_data = raw_data[len(signature):]
        computed_signature = hmac.new(KEY, read_data, hashlib.sha256).digest() # not .hexdigest()
        if hmac.compare_digest(computed_signature, read_signature):
            userDeserialized = pickle.loads(read_data)
            print (userDeserialized.name)
```

Output:

```
david
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as file_object:
    #Adding the signature to the data
    print(type(serialized))
    print(type(signature))
    #serializedStr = serialized.decode('utf-8')
    s = bytearray(signature)
    s.extend(bytes(serialized, 'utf-8'))
    file_object.write(s)
```